# How to map and reduce child values from FirebaseListObservable

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to sum up test scores, my data looks like this

```
   { testResult: 
      { foo:
         {foo1: x},
         {foo2: y}
      },
      { bar:
         {bar1: z}
```

'foo' and 'bar' are meaningful subcategories of questions, child-nodes hold questionIDs and corresponding scores. I need to sum up scores ordered by categories. I query the list like this

```
let res = this._dbref.database.list('/bmzi-answers',{
      query: {
        orderByKey: true,
        equalTo: id
      }
    })
```

and displaying the result with `{{ res | async | json }}` shows me, that the query works. I get something like

```
[{"cat1":3, "cat2":3, "cat3":3, "$key":"cat"}]
```

How can I reduce the values in my component logic, to get the sum of all questions labeled cat* ?

I understand concepts like filter / map / reduce, but I am new to Reactive Javascript, Angular2 and AngularFire.

Please help and thank you in advance!

Edit: 
All children have the cat prefix, this is part of the domain / the questionnaire. This code

```
  let res = this.dbRef.database.list(`/bmzi-answers/${id}`)
                  .do((array) => { console.log(JSON.stringify(array)); })
                  .map((array) => array
                      .reduce((acc, element) => acc + element.$value, 0)
            )
  let score = res.subscribe(sum => {
                  console.log("score: " + sum)
              });
  return score;
```

produces this console output, the first time it's called:

```
[
    { "$key": "cat1", "$value": 3 },
    { "$key": "cat2", "$value": 3 },
    { "$key": "cat3", "$value": 3 }
]
score: [object Object]
```

and the second time this:

```
[]  
score: undefined  
[{"$value":3,"$key":"fitges1"}]
score: undefined  
[{"$value":3,"$key":"fitges1"},{"$value":3,"$key":"fitges2"}]
score: undefined 
[{"$value":3,"$key":"fitges1"},{"$value":3,"$key":"fitges2"},{"$value":3,"$key":"fitges3"}]  
score: undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example output suggests the following data:

```
{
    "bmzi-answers": {
        "cat": {
            "cat1": 3,
            "cat2": 3,
            "cat3": 3
        }
    }
}
```

Your query uses `orderByKey` and `equalTo` to obtain a list observable that emits an array. Provided the key exists, the query will only ever return an array containing a single object. It would be simpler to incorporate the key in the query's path, like this:

```
let res = this._dbref.database.list(`/bmzi-answers/${id}`);
```

The observable returned by this query will be an array containing the key's children (represented in the AngularFire way):

```
[
    { "$key": "cat1", "$value": 3 },
    { "$key": "cat2", "$value": 3 },
    { "$key": "cat3", "$value": 3 }
]
```

The RxJS `map` operator can be used to transform the emitted array to another value and the transformation can be performed using the `Array.proptype` functions with which you state you are familiar:

```
let id = "cat";
let regExp = new RegExp(`${id}\\d+`);
let res = this._dbref.database
    .list(`/bmzi-answers/${id}`)
    .map((array) => array
        .filter((element) => regExp.test(element.$key))
        .reduce((acc, element) => acc + element.$value, 0)
    );
```

If all children have the `cat` prefix, the `filter` is not required, but your question doesn't make clear whether or not that's the case.

Comment: This almost solved the problem, but when i subscribe to res, the value of `let score = res.subscribe(sum => console.log(sum))` is undefined, but the only for the first time score is evaluated. How can i guarantee, that the reduction is finished when subscribing to res?

Comment: The `reduce` is synchronous, so that's not the problem. If you add `do((array) => { console.log(JSON.stringify(array)); })` before the `map` operator, what is the first emitted array value that results in the `undefined` score?

Comment: It's [{"$value":3,"$key":"fitges1"},{"$value":3,"$key":"fitges2"},{"$value":3,"$key":"fitges3"}].

Comment: I don't know if it is appropriate, but I will post an answer to show the code.

Comment: If it's not an answer, don't post it as an answer. Add it to the question.

Comment: Ok, i'll move it there. Thank you very much.

Comment: It should be `console.log("score: " + sum)`. The `score` variable holds the subscription object.

Comment: Ok, now i get the desired value '9'. I can work with that, thank you.
I guess, understanding why the array that `do...` prints out is empty when calling for the second time would be worth another question.

Answer (score 2):

A stream emits data. An observable is a stream.

For example:

```
let stream = Rx.Observable.from([3,6,9])
```

This code creates an observable stream which emits 3 then 6 then 9

Now lets say we wanted to double those values:

```
let stream = Rx.Observable.from([3,6,9]).map((value) => {return value*2})
```

Now the stream emits 6, 12, 18.

Finally we could do:

```
let stream1 = Rx.Observable.from([3,6,9])
let stream2 = stream1.map((value) => {return value*2})
```

Now we can subscribe to stream1 or stream2 or both.

PS a `.reduce()` function is also available the same as the es5 `Array.reduce` function. You can do the same with streams as you can with Arrays.

An array is an in memory sequence. A stream is a sequence over time.

This is why we can easily convert an array to a stream. We could put intervals between each emit. etc

Comment: This helped to grasp the 'bigger picture' and reminded me to subscribe to the transformed observable. ;)
Thank you very much, god bless you too!