# How to query Firebase once and store that return value in local parameter?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

I am trying to sum up some values from a Firebase-Database with AngularFire2 and use them for further processing in my component logic.
With some advice, I was able to query and reduce the desired values ([How to map and reduce child values from FirebaseListObservable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41044645/how-to-map-and-reduce-child-values-from-firebaselistobservable)), but when I try to put them into a local variable for further processing, in the first run that value is always undefined.

I tried to use `first()` to ensure, that the observable runs only once and is finished with no results.

How can I get that values *once and only once* say, when a button is clicked?

This is my code:

```
//sum up scores for questions belonging to category 'id'
...
let scoresObservable = this.dbRef.database.list(`/question-answers/${id}`)
                        .first()
                        .map((array) => array.reduce((acc, element) => 
                                        acc + element.$value, 0));
let result;
let sub  = scoresObservable.subscribe(sum => {
                result = sum;
                console.log(`total for ${id}: ` + sum)
             });
return result;
```

That result is always 'undefinied' when this block is called for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The function you pass into `scoresObservable.subscribe` won't be called immediately (it will be called when `database.list` will retrieve data) so there is no value in `result` right after subscription.

If you want to show result in template and the code block is inside controller then you can do something like:

```
@Comopnent({
  ...
  template: '{{ result }}'
  ...
})
class SomeComponent {
  result: number;

  ...

  someFunc() {
    ...

    scoresObservable.subscribe(sum => {
      this.result = sum;
      console.log(`total for ${id}: ` + sum)
    }
}
```

Also, note that `subscribe` returns subscription and `total` doesn't look like appropriate name for it.